# Using switch statements with Mysql and php PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

So I can read two tables by using the following sql statement

```
$result = $dbc->query("SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 WHERE table1.column_name = 'variable' AND table2.column_name = 'variable2'")
```

Now I want to use a switch statement to  read from each row determined by the variable in the columns. so for example

```
$q = $result->fetch();

switch ($q['column_name']) {

case "i":
 echo ///results
 break;

case "e":
echo // different results
break;
default:
//whatever code
}
```

I'm trying to echo two types of images from the two different tables based on the string under the column_name. But the switch method doesn't echo anything so I must not be calling be reading string from the column_name, any help?

Here is the var_dump that I'm getting:

array(46) { ["ad_id"]=> string(1) "1" [0]=> string(1) "1" ["user_id"]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> string(1) "0" ["global"]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" ["title"]=> string(7) "Testing" [3]=> string(7) "Testing" ["categories"]=> string(15) "music altnindie" [4]=> string(4) "blog" ["location"]=> string(9) "australia" [5]=> string(7) "austria" ["description"]=> string(16) "New King in town" [6]=> string(8) "A new ad" ["link"]=> string(12) "www.link.com" [7]=> string(12) "www.link.com" ["link_clicks"]=> string(1) "0" [8]=> string(1) "0" ["image_file_path"]=> string(43) "******** 2015-03-07 00.48.33.png" [9]=> string(59) "adimages/11014891_660400880771405_6666691584554052971_n.jpg" ["thumb_file_path"]=> string(52) "********* 2015-03-07 00.48.33.png" [10]=> string(68) "*******-11014891_660400880771405_6666691584554052971_n.jpg" ["date_post"]=> string(19) "2015-05-15 11:14:32" [11]=> string(19) "2015-05-15 12:36:05" ["share_count"]=> string(1) "0" [12]=> string(1) "0" ["type"]=> string(5) "audio" [13]=> string(5) "image" [14]=> string(1) "1" [15]=> string(1) "0" [16]=> string(0) "" [17]=> string(7) "Testing" [18]=> string(15) "music altnindie" [19]=> string(9) "australia" [20]=> string(16) "New King in town" ["plays"]=> string(1) "0" [21]=> string(1) "0" [22]=> string(12) "www.link.com" [23]=> string(1) "0" ["audio_file_path"]=> string(50) "*******/audioI0n7Dr" [24]=> string(50) "*****/audioI0n7Dr" [25]=> string(43) "**** 2015-03-07 00.48.33.png" [26]=> string(52) "***** 2015-03-07 00.48.33.png" [27]=> string(19) "2015-05-15 11:14:32" [28]=> string(1) "0" [29]=> string(5) "audio" }

Comment: Could you do a `var_dump($q)` after `$q = $result->fetch()` and show us the structure (content)?

Comment: Is the 'column_name' index in the var_dump? What does: _`var_dump($q['column_name'])`_ display?

Comment: yes it is where it says ['type']=>Image/audio